# запуск php-src в отладчике

Tags: php, c

Хочу запустить примерно такой код из php-src в отладчике Clion:

```
int main(){

    size_t i;
    Bucket p;
    zval val;
    HashTable ht;

    zend_hash_init(&ht, 8, NULL, NULL, 1);

    for (i=0; i < ht.nTableSize; i++) {
        p   = ht.arData[i];
        val = p.val;
    }


    printf ("sizeof HT_DATA_SIZE:  %d\n", HT_DATA_SIZE((&ht)->nTableSize));
    printf ("sizeof HT_MIN_MASK:   %d\n", HT_MIN_MASK);
    printf ("sizeof HT_HASH_SIZE:  %d\n", HT_HASH_SIZE((&ht)->nTableMask) );
    printf ("sizeof HT_SIZE:       %d\n", HT_SIZE(&ht));
}
```

Comment: И в чём проблема?

Comment: Не знаю как заставить работать подобный код. Получается использовать структуры данных из PHP только внутри самого PHP, например, в виде готового расширения. А мне для отладки надо вот именно такой код, как я написал завести. Как это сделать?